# How can i calculate a field with elastic java api query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

We can calculate a result by the help of sql like this.

```
SELECT price * 1.18 as priceWithTax FROM items
```

How can i get calculated fields with elasticsearch and Java API as a field added to indexed document?

Comment: Use a script: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-specialized-queries.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've found out my querstion is not clear enough. I want to add a field with the evaluated value actually. Fields must be mapped with records.

Comment: Well, just add another field to your mappings and calculate it when you index or update a document. If you got many update, script at querry time should be the best solution. There isnot "view" like in sql in elasticsearch, you cant add a field and say my_field = 1.18 * other field on elasticsearch side.